# How do I replace cells in a Panda dataframe column based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

This post consists of two questions, touching on issues I have encountered when trying to replace elements in a Panda dataframe based on a given condition. I am new with Pandas, so any suggestions will be most helpful.

## 1: Modifying strings of a certain length

Consider column A in a Panda dataframe object, df:

```
SSIC
103
1040
1054
1065
107
```

I want to append the integer 0 to each cell that is of length less than four. That is, I want to obtain:

```
SSIC
0103
1040
1054
1065
0107
```

The values are of type float64.

Currently, I have used this method:

```
SSIC1 = df['SSIC'].astype('int64').astype(str)

for i,n in enumerate(SSIC1):
    if len(SSIC1[i]) == 4:
       SSIC1[i] = '0' + SSIC1[i]

df['SSIC'] = SSIC1
```

It works, but I wonder if it is rather long-winded. Is there a more direct way to resolve this?

## 2: Setting with Copy Warning when using where clause

I have the following two columns in a dataframe

```
A  B
2  1
3  4
4  6
5  4
5  2
```

I want to replace cells in column A that take on the value 5, with the values on the same row in B.

I have used the where condition:

```
df['A']=df['A'].where(df['A'] == 5, df['B'], inplace=True)
```

​But it gives me the following error:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
> value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
> if **name** == '**main**':

This warning did not occur the first time I ran it. Any ideas why it has popped up?

Comment: It seems that simply using `df['A'].where(df['A'] == 5, df['B'], inplace=True)` worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first part call the vectorised [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
In [167]:
df['SSIC'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)

Out[167]:
0    0103
1    1040
2    1054
3    1065
4    0107
Name: SSIC, dtype: object
```

You may not need the call `astype` if the `dtype` is already `str`

Comment: Wow, that's very neat. May I clarify what you mean when you call a function vectorised?

Comment: it means to operate on the entire df/series at once rather than iteratively a row/element at a time

Answer (score 1):

Use the dataframe.at[] function. That is:

df.at[row_index,column_name] = 'the desired assignment'

for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['iqbal',2,88]],columns=['name','roll','marks'],index=[0])
df.at[0,'name']= 'Joy'
```

`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it